# NLog - Says "Failed to create file" but correct files are created

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

The Nlog internal log file says:

> Warn FileTarget(Name=allfile): Failed to create file appender:
> C:\nlog-all-2023-05-26.log Exception:
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> 'C:\nlog-all-2023-05-26.log' is denied.

Why should I get this warning?

- C:\nlog-all-2023-05-26.log is not the file path specified in the Nlog config. It is "C:\Govmeeting\LOGS\nlog-all-2023-05-26.log".
- The correct file DOES get created and written to.

Here is the configuration in program.cs:

```
NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
builder.Host.UseNLog();
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("logfilesPath", "C:\Govmeeting\LOGS");
```

And here are the relevant lines from nlog.config:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="${gdc:item=logfilesPath}/nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}"
archiveEvery="Day" archiveFileName="${gdc:item=logfilesPath}/nlog-${shortdate}.log" />

<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
```

This happens with Nlog 5.1.5 and 4.7.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that Logger-output is generated before having assigned GDC-property `logfilesPath`. Causing the issue with writing to root-folder:

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\nlog-all-2023-05-26.log' is denied.
```

Maybe assign GDC-property very early:

```cs
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("logfilesPath", "C:\Govmeeting\LOGS"); // First thing
NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
builder.Host.UseNLog();
```

Comment: Your guess seemed to make a lot of sense. But when I did that, the internal log file itself was no longer was created!

Comment: You can check out my code if you want and try it there. https://github.com/govmeeting/govmeeting Open the repo folder in VsCode. Set debug launch config to "WebApp". Start debugging (F5). A "LOGS" folder will be created as a sibling to the repo folder. The log files are in that. The WebApp code is in src/WebUI/WebApp.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz Seems that `"logfilesPath"` comes from your config-file with fallback to appbasepath. Maybe just use a combination `${configsetting:Logging.LogfilesPath:whenEmpty=${appbasepath}}` instead of GDC (That you fail to setup correctly). See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer + https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-AppBasePath-layout-renderer

Comment: Yes, "logfilesPath" comes from my config-file. But I am not (and do not want to) fall back to appbasepath if missing. In production, "logfilesPath" is the full path and I use that. But in development, it's a relative path to the solution folder and I generate the full path . The GDC value does get set correctly and the log files appear where they should. But, I don't think that I should be calling "logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger()". I want to get the value of "logfilesPath" by myself and modify its value if dev.. What should I call?

Comment: @JohnPankowicz You can put in what you like as `whenEmpty=`-fallback. Just make sure the fallback gives a valid value. Else it will write in the root-folder, when no configsetting is available.